# How can I set a Butto.onClickListener in a Dialog?

Tags: android, button, dialog, listener

I've made a class MyDialog that extends Dialog.  Within, I'm trying to set click listeners to the buttons, but Eclipse is giving me issues.  Here's the problematic code:

```
private void setOnClickListeners() {
    myButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
}
```

Eclipse is showing OnClickListener as a DialogInterface.OnClickListener, which seems to be the root of the problem.  Can I make this work the same as it would from an Activity?

Answer (score 1):

Either import DialogInterface.OnClickListener, or do this

```
myButton.setOnClickListener( new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```

The reasons you have to do this is because there are differenet types of OnClickListeners.

Comment: To add to that, I always make it a point to fully qualify the `OnClickListener` in my code to avoid confusion. In your case, Eclipse probably recognizes the listener as `View.OnClickListener`.

Comment: Yeah, myButton.setOnClickListener keeps expecting a View.OnClickListener as its argument.  How do I get it to want a DialogInterface.OnClickListener?  I tried importing DialogInterface.OnClickListener and specifying my listener as a DialogInterface.OnClickListener, but it isn't working.